# Cannot visualize data in IBM Watson IoT Platform

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, iot, ibm-watson, watson-iot

I have a TI sensortag CC2650 connected to a Raspberry Pi using Node-Red and I have connected them to IBM Watson IoT output.

I am trying to create a card in a board in IBM Watson IoT Platform in order to see the data but when I click on *"boards" => "Usage overview"* I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined at https://orgID.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/bundle.main.4dd68f5c0fb0629c2282.js:4:599791

(orgID is my organization ID)